# Easiest way to submit data via PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP, and have spent 10 hours trying to figure this problem out.

**The goal** is to take all data entered into this order form, and send it to my email via PHP.

*I have 2 questions:*

**1.** I can get PHP to send data from a single menu item (example: Mexican Tortas), but how do I get PHP to send data from multiple items (example: Mexican Tortas, Fish Sandwich and Hamburger)?

**2.** How do I tell PHP to not send data from menu items that don't have the "How Many?" or "Customize It?" text fields filled out?

If you could provide a super simple example (or a link to a learning resource) I would really appreciate it.

Thank you,
Abijah

---

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "test@mywebsite.com"; 
$subject = "New Order";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$customize = $_POST['customize'];

}

$body = "Name: $name_field\nPhone: $phone_field\n\nItem: $item\nQuantity: $quantity\nCustomize: $customize";

echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

?>
```

---

**HTML**

```
<form action="neworder.php" method="POST">

<div class ="item">
<img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/mexicantortas.jpg">
<h1>Mexican Torta - $8.50</h1>
<input name="item" type="hidden" value="Mexican Torta"/>
<h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
<input name="quantity" type="text"/>
<h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
<textarea name="customize"/></textarea>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->

<div class ="item">
<img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/fishsandwich.jpg">
<h1>Fish Sandwich - $8.50</h1>
<input name="item" type="hidden" value="Fish Sandwich"/>
<h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
<input name="quantity" type="text"/>
<h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
<textarea name="customize"/></textarea>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->

<div class ="item">
<img style="float:left; margin-right:15px; border:1px Solid #000; width:200px; height:155px;" src="images/hamburgers.jpg">
<h1>Hamburger w/ Fries - $7.00</h1>
<input name="item" type="hidden" value="Fish Sandwich"/>
<h2>How Many? <font color="#999999">Ex: 1, 2, 3...?</font></h2> 
<input name="quantity" type="text"/>
<h3>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></h3> 
<textarea name="customize"/></textarea>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->

<div class="horizontal_form">
<div class="form">
<h2>Place Your Order Now: <font size="3"><font color="#037B41">Fill in the form below, and we'll call you when your food is ready to be picked up...</font></font></h2>
<p class="name">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="text-align:center;" onClick="this.value='';" value="Enter your name"/>
</p>
<p class="phone">  
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" style="text-align:center;" onClick="this.value='';" value="Enter your phone #"/>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Place Order" name="submit"/>
</p>
</div><!-- FORM -->
</div><!-- HORIZONTAL_FORM -->

</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking to have PHP only submit data into an email that is from the filled out fields in your form?  If so, why don't you just write php script to get the length of all the input strings and if they are null not include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use '[]', as it groups multiple input fields to an array.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

  $to = "test@mywebsite.com"; 
  $subject = "New Order";

  $order = array();
  $order['name']  = $_POST['name'];
  $order['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];

  $food = $_POST['food'];

  foreach ($food as $type => $value)
    if (strlen($value['quantity']) > 0) // assuming 'customize' is optional
      $order[$type] = $value;

  print_r($order);
}

?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Order now!</title>
  <style>label,input,textarea {display:block}</style>
<body>
<?php // You need enctype for '[]' support' ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class ="item">
    <label>Mexican Torta - $8.50</label>

    <b>How Many?</b> 
    <input name="food[mexican_torta][quantity]" type="text">

    <b>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></b> 
    <textarea name="food[mexican_torta][customize]"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class ="item">
    <label>Fish - $3.50</label>

    <b>How Many?</b> 
    <input name="food[fish][quantity]" type="text">

    <b>Customize It? <font color="#999999">Ex: No Lettuce, Extra Cheese...</font></b> 
    <textarea name="food[fish][customize]"></textarea>
  </div>

  <h2>Place Your Order Now:</h2>

  <em>Fill in the form below, and we'll call you when your food is ready to be picked up.</em>

  <label>Enter your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">

  <label>Enter your phone nr.</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone">

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

---

User submits (for example I left the fish blank) and you get

```
Array ( 
 [name] => Fab 
 [phone] => 1212
 [mexican_torta] => Array ( [quantity] => 2 [customize] => Test ) 
)
```

Play around a bit with the '[]' to get the array output you really desire. The print_r will show you exactly what you get. From here it is really easy to put the food details in the e-mail

Comment: Could you possibly provide a reference example of how the php file should be setup?

Comment: I modified the example I gave, you can copy + paste it and it should give you the basic understanding I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need unique form field names.  In other words, you can't have repeated items of the form:

```
<input name="quantity" type="text"/>
```

Instead, you'll need unique names, such as:

```
<input name="quantity_fish" type="text"/>
```

You can then use PHP to parse $_POST and throw out empty fields if you'd like.